# Spring boot: default localtion for static page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a small project using Spring boot (created via http://start.spring.io/):

1) I have a controller:

```
@Controller
public class RootController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

2) In my folder: src/main/resources/static/, I have added a file: index.html.

Unfortunalty, when I try to access to it via 'http://localhost:8080/', I get a 404 error. Why ?

I found two solutions to solve this problem but I guess it's not the most easy solution proposed by Spring boot (?):

- Define manually a configuration for InternalResourceViewResolver.
- Move index.html in 'src/main/resources/template' folder and add dependency to 'mustache' library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the html file inside src/main/resources/template folder.Your css and js need to be inside src/main/resources/folder

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html file must be in the templates folder.

[image]

Comment: I already test it but I still have error 404. It only work if I add dependency to spring-boot-starter-mustache in pom.xml. But I don't want to add this dependency.

Comment: The error is: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Jul 27 12:00:43 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: this error is the default error message provided by springboot. it doesnt mean that your app is faulty. You just have to configure InternalResourceViewResolver.

Answer (score 0):

Try src/main/webapp/index.html